# Tunnel 2 server

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, ssh-tunneling, webserver

I am looking for a solution to tunnel two servers to each other.
That is, in such a way that all data is sent from the source server to the destination server in an encrypted form and cannot be overheard.
Can any of my friends guide and help me in this work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify which connections you would like to build between the servers.

Let's say you have a webserver on localhost:80 on machine A and you want to connect to this port via SSH from machine B.

You could do something like this on Machine A:

```
ssh -L 1337:localhost:80 machineb.name.here
```

Now you can connect to localhost:1337 on Machine A and the traffic will get routed through the tunnel on Machine B's port 80.
Effectively encrypting the plain HTTP traffic for the outside world.

Another possibility that comes to mind is using WireGuard, has similarities to say an IPSEC tunnel but very easy to setup.
This will allow you to create a direct connection between the 2 machines and encrypt anything that flows in between.

See [this](https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/).

Again without knowing what you want to do this is difficult to answer.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, my friend.
Our general procedure has been as follows:
We have set up vpn cisco or v2ray on the server of other countries, now to connect to these servers we want the user to go to the intermediate server which is inside our country, then automatically, through the communication tunnel. be directed to the server abroad and receive the answer from the same way.
The important point is that we want the tunnel connection of these two servers to be encrypted so that the domestic server provider does not notice the data content.

Comment: Do you have a simple solution for the WireGuard method so that we can create such a tunnel for communication between two Linux servers?

Comment: Such a thing could be done quite easily with SSH. As mentioned in the example. Could forward the port to the intermediate server and then forward it again to the local site, that way the user can connect locally and the TCP hops through the SSH tunnels to the endpoint, or you could use the -J (jump option) to hop through the intermediate automatically. It would be much easier to explain with a drawing.